# hector_quadrotor-gazebo1.9 doesn't respond to command velocity

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I installed the hector_quadrotor from source (hydro and 1.9 gazebo) and launched the file “quadrotor_empty_world.launch”. Everything seems to be ok, empty_world with one quadrotor,   until I provided to the quadrotor a velocity command using “rostopic pub” and the quadrotor doesn’t move at all.
I verified via “rqt_graph” that gazebo is connected to the right topic (/cmd_vel) and also verified  if the data is published on the topic. Everything seems to be normal and I don’t know what else I can check. Any idea about this problem?
Thank you for any help with this issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6154/hector_quadrotor-gazebo1.9-doesn%27t-respond-to-command-velocity/) by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi for me this command works:

`rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0, 0, 1]' '[0, 0, 0]'`

The problem might be that your quadcopter is not flying.

If the quadcopter is on the ground it needs a Twist with positive linear.z value.
The program will print *Engaging motors!*
As soon as you land on the ground the programm will print *Shutting down motors!* Which will mean you have to start it again.

Let me no if this does not solve your problem...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-05-07**:
Hi evilBiber, thanks a lot for your tip. it worked and quadrotor took off. But I observed after awhile the quadrotor get frozen (motionless) on the space. I checked the quadrotor' pose via "rostopic echo /ground_truth/state" and the pose values are the same after reaching certain altitude (~952m). Also, I provided 0 command velocity (rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msg/Twist '[0, 0, 0,]' '[0, 0, 0]') to the quad to land on the ground but the quad stayed motionless. Do you know how to land the quad on the ground?. Thanks a lot again

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2014-05-08**:
you have to use negative z values for going down.

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-05-08**:
Thanks alot again! your tip worked and quad landed

**Comment by [vinaykumar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1184/vinaykumar/) on 2015-04-17**:
Thanks Robert! This helped me! :)